# Symfony (PHP) – Send mail in background without queue

Tags: php, symfony, email

I have a Symfony application that send eMails. The number of eMails to send is low and I want to send them without use of a queue. However, the Swiftmailer take about 20 seconds to preform this operation. It could be a limitation of a SMTP server. I have limited capabilities to configure the web server.

I would like the PHP script to send a whole response to a user and then finish task with an eMail in background.

## What have I tried?

The Swiftmailer memory spool doesn’t help. The function `fastcgi_finish_request` doesn’t work and user have to wait for the whole script to finish.

I cannot fork the script too. The fork function is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could spool using files, as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html#spool-using-files):

If you don't want to use a queue, you could launch the sending of the email asynchronously. You could create a service that will send your email and then call it asynchronously using something like [krlove/async-service-call-bundle](https://github.com/krlove/async-service-call-bundle).

If you don't want to use that bundle and do it yourself, you could create a command that will spool your email and call it with something like:

```
$proc_command = 'php bin/console yourcommand > /dev/null 2>&1 &';
$proc = popen($proc_command, 'r');
pclose($proc);
```

Comment: The file spool is a kind of queue. I want to avoid this.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused when I read about the memory spool. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I have limited capabilities to configure the web server.

I saw this and I'm afraid you can't install anything, but let me share my thoughts.

First option is POSTFIX if you're able to install it to the server

- It sends messages asynchronously i.e no need to wait while email is
  really sent. All queueing is implemented inside postfix
- It can be configured to send email via External SMTP Server
- It has [sendmail compatibility interface](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html), so you can replace your system native sendmail with postfix and configure Swiftmailer to use sendmail as transport

Second option is to use some cloud email services (via SMTP or REST API) and hope that it will work fast enough